# BigQuery Double Imports

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using Google BigQuery from app engine. I have a cron job that runs every 15 minutes to do an export to BigQuery. Randomly though, the import runs twice. However, the appengine logs do not reflect this. I have a set of blobs I maintain to write data to bigquery with, and duplicate data is not being written to them. Has anyone else had bigquery problems with duplicate imports? Again, my appengine logs show the imports happening only one time, and I'm kind of at a loss how to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to troubleshoot is to look at your import jobs. You can do this using the bq tool by running `bq ls -j` to list the jobs you've run, and `bq show -j <job_id>` to show details about particular jobs.

We've not heard of any other cases of duplicate loads. One idea to prevent this is to give your import jobs an id ... by default one gets created for you (it will look like job_). Job ids are enforced to be unique within a project, so if you generate an id per import you intend to do, if a double import is triggered, the second one will fail immediately because the job id will already exist.

Comment: Very valuable information!!! Especially the job names. Didn't know that it had the same semantics as task queue in that regard

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem where the jobs seem to have imported twice even though our logs shows it was submitted only once.

Also looked into the jobs and the above command shows it was successfully processed only once.

Note that since the job was only submitted once, not sure how controlling the job_id will help in this case. It seems to be something internal to BigQuery that might have caused the jobs to duplicate?

Let me know if you need anything from my end to investigate.

Thanks,